# Proper way of preventing GPU access with Core Image when app is in background

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm experiencing crashes from customers, with the following backtrace:

```
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib          0x3542ae2e gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient + 10
1   IMGSGX543RC2GLDriver                0x30bbf5e5 SubmitPacketsIfAny + 245
2   GLEngine                            0x32f827db glFinish_Exec + 167
3   CoreImage                           0x31fb85b7 CI::GLESContext::recursive_render(CI::Node const*, CGRect, bool) + 219
4   CoreImage                           0x31fbb351 CI::GLESContext::render(CI::Node*,     CGRect) + 41
5   CoreImage                           0x31fc2901 CI::image_get_cgimage(CI::Context*, CI::Image*, CGRect, CGColorSpace*, CI::PixelFormat) + 1313
6   CoreImage                           0x31fa8427 -[CIContext createCGImage:fromRect:format:colorSpace:] + 487
7   CoreImage                           0x31fa81e9 -[CIContext createCGImage:fromRect:] + 89
8   App                                 0x0013c9db -[PZTiledImageLayer drawInContext:] (PZTiledImageLayer.m:129)
```

Which are due to accessing the GPU when the app is in background (not allowed).

The code leading to this crash is this:

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
{
    cg_image = [self.imageContext createCGImage:im fromRect:rclip];
}
```

This means the app changes state after my check, but before GPU is accessing within the Core Image API.

What is the proper way of handling the situation of app background state when using this Core Image API?

Comment: Is this happening on the main thread or in a worker thread?

Comment: Any proved solution for this?

Comment: @rsebbe, have found anything?

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening on a background thread, you could try moving it to the main thread. That way the execution of this function is not interleaved with the AppDelegate callback

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

and you can implement some signalling there without worrying about concurrency.